# Do not find DeleteOnSubmit method

Tags: c#, .net, database, linq, linq-to-sql

Im want to delete rows from a table that in my data base.
i have the member

```
private static WeightScaleEntities Weight = new Weight();
```

this member contains my database. in the data base i have table: User_Activity.

I want to delete rows from user activity by given i_UserActivityId, as follow:

```
//Get the rows for delete
var deleteUserActivities = from details in Weight.User_Activity
                                   where details.Id == i_UserActivityId
                                   select details;
```

Now i want to delete this rows, so i tried to do:

```
foreach (var item in deleteUserActivities)
{
         m_WeightScaleEntities.User_Activity.*
}
```

and i dont get the method DeleteOnSubmit!

Why?
there is another option???

Comment: Is User_Activity derived from DataContext?

Comment: @alexn he derived from EntityObject

Comment: My bad. I meant Table<T>, which is the type containing DeleteOnSubmit.

Comment: WeightScaleEntities derived from ObjectContext

Comment: Is this LINQ to SQL or Entity Framework? The answer indicatest EF, but the question is tagged linq-to-sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`User_Activity.*`: is that a typo?

What I think you want is:

```
foreach (var item in deleteUserActivities)
{
     Weight.DeleteObject(item);
}
```

And then `SaveChanges()` on the object context.

BTW, a static object context is not a good idea. You should carefully control the life cycle of object contexts.

Comment: Thanks! i didnt understand what you mean by "BTW, a static object context is not a good idea. You should carefully control the life cycle of object contexts."

Comment: I mean: it is better to use an instance variable. A static variable is scoped to the class, not to an instance. So, unless you do `Weight = null;` somewhere, the object context is never garbage collected.

Comment: A late comment: I cam across [this link](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/10linqmyths.aspx), which puts it better then I could (myth 10).

Answer (score 1):

There is more than one way to execute deletion in Entity Framework,
You must take into account what are the values that you want to delete? one Row or more.
when you need to delete on Row from table we can use these ways:

```
// first way
        using (WeightScaleEntities db = new WeightScaleEntities())
        {
            var deleteUserActivities = from details in db.User_Activity
                                       where details.Id == i_UserActivityId
                                       select details;
            if (deleteUserActivities.Count() > 0)
            {
                db.deleteUserActivities.Remove(deleteUserActivities.First());
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
```

this line `deleteUserActivities.Count()>0` to check if you have result in the Query or not.
and this `deleteUserActivities.First()` if the query return set of rows delete the first. "to make the process more secure if you don't know about the data in the table"

```
// second way
        using (WeightScaleEntities db = new WeightScaleEntities())
        {
            var deleteUserActivities = (from details in db.User_Activity
                                        where details.Id == i_UserActivityId
                                        select details).SingleOrDefault();
            if (deleteUserActivities != null)
            {
                db.User_Activity.Remove(deleteUserActivities);
                // or use this line
                //db.Entry(deleteUserActivities).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Deleted;
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
```

You can also use Single or SingleOrDefault to get a single object. Single or SingleOrDefault will throw an exception, if the result contains more than one element. Use Single or SingleOrDefault where you are sure that the result would contain only one element. If the result has multiple elements then there must be some problem.

Also, if you need to remove one or multi rows use this way:

```
using (WeightScaleEntities db = new WeightScaleEntities())
        {
            var deleteUserActivities = (from details in db.User_Activity
                                       where details.Id == i_UserActivityId
                                       select details).ToList<User_Activity>(); //<User_Activity> her name of your DbSet
            foreach(deleteObject in deleteUserActivities)
            {
                db.Entry(deleteObject).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Deleted;    
            }
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Best Regards
and sorry about English language.

Answer (score 0):

```
using(WeightScaleEntities db=new WeightScaleEntities())
        {
            var deleteUserActivities = from details in db.User_Activity
                                       where details.Id == i_UserActivityId
                                       select details;
            if (deleteUserActivities.Count()>0)
            {
                db.deleteUserActivities.Remove(deleteUserActivities.First());
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Wouldn´t that delete only the first element in deleteUserActivities?

Comment: Please, explain how your code helps. Code-only answers are discouraged.

Comment: There is more than one way to execute deletion in Entity Framework:

Comment: There is more than one way to execute deletion in Entity Framework:

Comment: There is more than one way to execute deletion in Entity Framework look at another Answer to me

Comment: deleteUserActivities is not a member of db.